# Problems opening TOR

Tags: bridge, proxy

Im having problem when opening TOR, as I open it it says "Connected to bridge" I believe its having problems cause I tried to use TOR with a proxy in the past (if I remember correctly). It is the latest version that Im aware of.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried not using a bridge, or using a different bridge? It's possible that the bridge you were previously using is no longer available.

Without knowing what custom modifications you made to the browser to make it use a proxy, there is little information for us to help you get it working. If that doesn't help, download a new copy of Tor Browser and try starting it.

**Edit:** The solution ended up being to delete the application data manually, which on MacOS requires following the steps at https://tb-manual.torproject.org/uninstalling/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that I have to open the app to change the settings(I think). And yes, I have tried deleting TOR and installing it again but as soon as I open it the same happens. I don't know why this happens, I mean, shouldn't it be "blank" when I delete it and install it again? Anyway, is there anything I can do to give you more useful info in order to fix the problem?

Comment: So you reinstalled the Tor Browser, and if you try starting it without a bridge, what is last step that it gets to? Are there any warning or error messages in the text from "Copy Tor Log to Clipboard", and if not, what are the last three messages?

Comment: I think its best if I describe the whole process, I download it, open it, copy it to applications, open it and there the window shown on the second picture appears, it never give me the option to run it without any bridges or proxys, just uses the last configurations I guess. I can open a new tab when right-clicking it, but it appears frozen and doesn't respond to any input apart from cmd+r (reload the page) it doesn't let me go to settings or to anything else to be honest. Ill add a picture of the clipboard´s last three lines of code. Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realize this was Mac. Can you try following this guide for macOS to remove the application data? https://tb-manual.torproject.org/uninstalling/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: Glad you got it working!